# DataFrame is not giving me the plot i need

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I use k-means to the Mergory dataset and then i want the plot of two columns, the hospitalization vs fried columns so i write the code below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels)

plt.scatter(Mergory['hospitalization_one_year'], Mergory['fried'], color=colors, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
    plt.scatter(*centroid, color=colmap[idx+1])
plt.show()
```

then i get this error but i dont know what to do and why i get this.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-93db5ccc140c> in <module>
      3 colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels)
      4 
----> 5 plt.scatter(Mergory['hospitalization_one_year'], Mergory['fried'], color=colors, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
      6 for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
      7     plt.scatter(*centroid, color=colmap[idx+1])

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)
   2845         verts=verts, edgecolors=edgecolors,
   2846         plotnonfinite=plotnonfinite, **({"data": data} if data is not
-> 2847         None else {}), **kwargs)
   2848     sci(__ret)
   2849     return __ret

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1599     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1600         if data is None:
-> 1601             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1602 
   1603         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4452             self._parse_scatter_color_args(
   4453                 c, edgecolors, kwargs, xshape, yshape,
-> 4454                 get_next_color_func=self._get_patches_for_fill.get_next_color)
   4455 
   4456         if plotnonfinite and colors is None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in _parse_scatter_color_args(c, edgecolors, kwargs, xshape, yshape, get_next_color_func)
   4225         if kwcolor is not None:
   4226             try:
-> 4227                 mcolors.to_rgba_array(kwcolor)
   4228             except ValueError:
   4229                 raise ValueError("'color' kwarg must be an mpl color"

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba_array(c, alpha)
    290         pass
    291     # Convert one at a time.
--> 292     result = np.empty((len(c), 4), float)
    293     for i, cc in enumerate(c):
    294         result[i] = to_rgba(cc, alpha)

TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` does not even take `color` as an argument ?

Comment: @BcK [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) does take `color` as an argument, although the docs could be clearer on that point...

Comment: Is `Mergory` a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

Answer (score 0):

`colors` must be a list. So,

before:

```
colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels)
```

after:

```
colors = list(map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels))
```

This will work.

Comment: i get the NameError: name 'colmap' is not defined.

Comment: If you use 3 colors, `colmap = {1: 'r', 2: 'g', 3: 'b'}` , for example. If you need 4 or more, add something like 4:'y', ...